# System.Windows.MessageBox: Yes Button is missing

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF Application (.NET 3.5) I create a MessageBox like this:

```
if (System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Eine neue Version von Qualisoft steht zum Download bereit. Möchten Sie diese installieren?", "Neue Qualisoft Version", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
{
...
}
```

One of my customers get this result:

[image]

I tested this on about 10 systems and I cant reproduce this result.

Does anyone know why the Yes Button is missing?

Comment: The code mentioned above cannot give the output displayed in the image. Unless there is some other code which is causing this problem. If you use the above code, it should definitely work.

Comment: maybe he is kidding you ;)

Comment: Doesn't reproduce here. The fact that the text in your code snippet is different than the one in the image makes me suspect the error is elsewhere. Can you post the *actual* code that doen't work?

Comment: Also, please specify your .NET framework version, and whether you're using a language pack (probably)

Comment: That code can't produce that exact dialog (albeit just for the translations). **Give your real code, not a sample!**

Comment: Can't reproduce here, even with the updated code - I get both "Yes" and "No". I suspect a layout issue with the German language pack.

Comment: Sry. I edited the code. I use .NET 3.5 and installed the GER Language Pack.

Comment: maybe try with english? seems to be localization issue, other buttons work fine?

Comment: @mikus: I cant try it in english. I dont have access to the system where the problem occurs. All other Buttons work fine Yes. But this is the only one MessageBox i use in the Application.

Comment: a quick workaround would be to use Ok/Cancel then :) otherwise just follow the Patrick answer, there is not much more you can do to strip all the potentially problematic layers. BTW. maybe the system actually fails to show other application's dialogs like that?

Answer (score 3):

This issue is **NOT** (directly) related to .NET. WPF actually redirects the call to the [operating system](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505(v=vs.85).aspx), to be specific by [this call](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/MessageBox.cs,508):

```
UnsafeNativeMethods.MessageBox(...)
```

There can be other things that go wrong. This might be caused by a language pack or something, but I doubt that. Also video card drivers sometimes mess up UI controls. There is not much to go on now since it can't be reproduced easily.

You have to go check by taking out parts that might be the issue. Start in safe mode and check if the issue persists. Try to make a new default application with just this call. Is the behavior still the same? Then continue. Else something in your code might be causing this.

Answer (score 3):

Your customer is playing a prank on you and sent you a photo-shopped screenshot.  Probably a not-so-subtle hint that he's a bit tired of having to constantly deal with new versions.  Something like that.

The native MessageBox() winapi function does not have an option to *only* display the No button.

Just prank him right back and recommend he drags the machine to a 4th story window and let it slip.  With the advice that opening the window first is entirely optional.